# Add exception to htaccess redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^news/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+?/(.+)$ /news [R=301,L]
```

This works how I want it to, for example if I go to /news/some-category/some-post it just redirects to /news which is great. However it is also affecting my uploads folder. Take the following URL for example:

```
/news/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Emily-286x300.jpg
```

This gets redirected to /news as well so all my images are broken. Is there a way to tweak this rule so that it doesn't affect the wp-content/uploads directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/news/some-category/some-post` represent a 3-level subdirectories, you can use this rule

```
RewriteRule ^news/[^/]+/[^/]+/?$ /news [R=301,L]
```

Also, please note you'll have to clear your browser's cache before trying again such link `/news/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Emily-286x300.jpg` (my rule will not match it but your last rule does and it's in browser's cache)